# How to Create a text File in Asp.net Core Application

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-mvc-2.1

I am new To Dot-net Core Application How to Create a text File in Asp.net Core Application Please provide Me some resource

Comment: Try this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-write-text-to-a-file). It should contain all you need.

Answer (score 5):

> How to Create a text File in Asp.net Core Application

If you'd like to create a text file at specific folder of your ASP.NET Core MVC project, you can refer to the following code snippet.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IHostingEnvironment _env;

    public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath, @"TxtFiles\" + "MyTest.txt");

        using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(path))
        {
            byte[] content = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("Hello World");

            fs.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
        }

        //code logic here
        //...

        return View();
    }
```

Folder `TxtFiles` for saving text file(s)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it's pretty much the same as the classic .NET

```
using System;
using System.IO;


        string path= Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

        using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(path, "myfile.txt")))
        {
                outputFile.WriteLine("Hello world!");
        }
```

Hope it helps.